# Send a line on vim to another pane or section in tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

I am trying to use a vim+tmux setup to write code in R.

For that, I need to find a way to send lines (better if motions) to a terminal in other tmux pane (or section, if possible) which is running R.

Looks like a simple task, but I don't understand much about vim's variables or functions, and I'm new on tmux.

With some research, I found the `tmux send-keys` command, which looks pretty promising, so I'm currently able to map something like

`:silent ! tmux send-keys -t 0:0.0 'print("test")' Enter`

and that effectively runs the "print" command in the pane "0:0.0" (I'm thinking in always open a section with the same name for easy of reference). No idea if that's efficient, and no idea about how to substitute the `'print()'` to some editor's text.

The final goal is to have keybindings like `<localleader>rr` to run a line in R, `<localleader>r[motion]` to run the motion, and something similar to run selected code.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider the possibility that others may have had the same idea before? https://github.com/zweifisch/replit.vim, https://michaellindon.github.io/lindonslog/linux-unix/send-lines-code-vim-r-julia-python-repl-slime/index.html, etc. Your favourite search engine is your friend.

Comment: Also see http://s3.amazonaws.com/mps/slime.vim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, but you can try the plugin [vimtux](https://github.com/ChHaeni/vimtux). It allows you to select a specific tmux pane, where you can send text to this tmux pane using (also) motions (e.g. `<leader>rap`, `<leader>rgg` etc.).

Comment: Never is too late! This looks exactly what I need!
(I stopped this project for a while)

Answer (score 0):

With some minor tweaks to [slime.vim](http://s3.amazonaws.com/mps/slime.vim), you can do this by putting the following file in your vim plugin dir (eg `$HOME/.vim/plugin`)

```
function Send_to_Pane(text)
  if !exists("g:tmux_target")
    call Tmux_Vars()
  end
  echo system("tmux send-keys -t " . g:tmux_target . " '" . substitute(a:text, "'", "'\\\\''", 'g') . "'")
endfunction

function Tmux_Pane_Names(A,L,P)
  return system("tmux list-panes -a | awk '/active/ {printf \"%s:%s\n\", $1, $2}' FS=:")
endfunction

function Tmux_Vars()
  if !exists("g:tmux_target")
    let g:tmux_target = "%1"
  end
  let g:tmux_target = input("session:window.pane> ", "%1", "custom,Tmux_Pane_Names")
endfunction

vmap <C-c><C-c> "ry :call Send_to_Pane(@r)<CR>
nmap <C-c><C-c> vip<C-c><C-c>
nmap <C-c>v :call Tmux_Vars()<CR>
```

Now, in vim, if you type `<C-c><C-c>`, the current paragraph will be sent to the pane (assuming `vim` was built with the `textobjects` feature enabled).  In visual mode, the selected text will be sent.  To send just the current line, you can use linewise-visual by doing `V<C-c><C-c>`. (`vim` doesn't really have builtin support for linewise text objects, but there are plugins available.)

Note that the correct value for the target pane can easily be determined by inspecting $TMUX_PANE in the process running in that pane.  You can use specific targets like `0:2.1`, but the above uses `%1` as a default.   This is probably a bad default to use. YMMV